# How can I train TensorFlow to read variable length numbers on an image?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I have a set of images like this

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

And I'm trying to train TensoFlow on python to read the numbers on the images.

I'm new to machine learn and on my research I found a solution to a similar problem that uses CTC to train/predict variable length data on an image.

I'm trying to figure out if I should use CTC or find a way to create a new image for every number of the image that I already have.

Like if the number of my image is 213, then I create 3 new images to train the model with the respective numbers 2, 1, 3 also using them as labels. I'm looking for tutorials or even TensorFlow documentation that can help me on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the case of text CTC absolutely makes sense: you don't want to split a text (like "213") into "2", "1", "3" manually, because it often is difficult to segment the text into individual characters.
CTC, on the other hand, just needs images and the corresponding ground-truth texts as input for training. You don't have to manually take care of things like alignment of chars, width of chars, number of chars. CTC handles that for you.

I don't want to repeat myself here, so I just point you to the tutorials I've written about text recognition and to the source code:

- [Build a Handwritten Text Recognition System using TensorFlow](https://towardsdatascience.com/2326a3487cd5)
- [SimpleHTR: a TensorFlow model for text-recognition](https://github.com/githubharald/SimpleHTR)

You can use the SimpleHTR model as a starting point. To get good results, you will have to generate training data (e.g. write a rendering tool which renders realsitic looking examples) and train the model from scratch with that data (more details on training can be found in the README).